# Selenium autotest can't login with good credentials, but human can

Tags: java, testing, selenium, testng, autotest

This is my selenium java test. 
I can login using my credentials on website, but selenium automatic test can not!

What could be the reason?

```
public void main() {
  WebElement phone_field= firefox.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"login-form\"]/div[1]/span/input"));
  WebElement password_field= firefox.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"login-form\"]/div[2]/span/input[@name=\"password\"]"));

  Assert.assertNotNull(phone_field);
  Assert.assertNotNull(password_field);

  Assert.assertTrue(phone_field.isDisplayed());
  Assert.assertTrue(password_field.isDisplayed());

  phone_field.clear();
  password_field.clear();

  phone_field.sendKeys("5555555555");
  password_field.sendKeys("222kek");

  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(firefox,3);
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='form-wrapper']")));

  firefox.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.button.blue")).click();
  String newUrl = firefox.getCurrentUrl();
  System.out.println(newUrl);
```

[image: se]

Might it be the case that I need to make selenium wait for a bit,i.e. it presses on the blue login button too quickly?

Comment: and also check wether it is in iframe or not. If it is, you need to switch to iframe before doing any operations in that.

Comment: friend as a suggestion it would be easier if you could share the url of the page you are working on. It could be faster to propose solutions and test the issue. As an example in such situation I would try using action chains https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AdvancedUserInteractions#A_single_action

Answer (score 0):

so i found the answer myself!  simply do this:

```
phone_field.clear() ;
phone_field.sendkeys("234234") ;
```

right after you clear you should 'type in' data!
this will not work:

```
field1.clear();
field2.clear() ;

....
field1.sendkeys() ;
field2.sendkeys() ;
```